# What does lieber/liebe mean when used in a greeting?

Tags: meaning, translation, meaning-in-context, german-to-english

> Guten Morgen liebe Marie.

Is it affectionate, flirtatious, or just a greeting you would send to any friend? The example is coming from a guy.

Comment: You can translate it with "dear" like in an English letter "Dear Marie".

Answer (score 1):

> > Guten Morgen liebe Marie.
>
> Is it affectionate, flirtatious, or just a greeting you would send to any friend?

Well, *affectionate* in the sense of *cordial* yes.
*Flirtatious* usually not, at least not in a context used at work or for a friend<sup>1</sup>.

It can be used for any colleague or friend.

If used in a romantic relationship, it would rather be

> > Guten Morgen ***meine*** liebe Marie.

---

<sup>1)</sup><sub>Though in those contexts it's also not that common. I'd be prepared, that some hammer thing I broke, or bad news might be stated after, and it was just a phrase to attenuate what's said next.</sub>

Comment: In a romantic context, you could also say *Guten Morgen **liebste** Marie.*

Answer (score 0):

> > Guten Morgen liebe Marie.
> >     Is it affectionate, flirtatious, or just a greeting you would send to any friend? The example is coming from a guy.

As far as *my experience* goes this can mean all your listed intentions. Thus it completely depends on the persons communicating and the context.

- some people use it all the day to anyone
- some people use it to anyone they call by first name
- some people use it only to people they consider "(close) friends"
- some people use it only to people they are in or assume a "romantic" relationship
- some people use it only in reply after gotten addressed that way

That said, *I* would assume the person using that phrase somehow emotionally bonds with Marie/ "the other one" thus the intention is unclear from the sentence alone.

Why not a clear "romantic relationship"? Because some people don't use that phrase at all. => there is no 100 % boundary when "romance" begins.

Why not a clear "never on workplace"? Because some people use it on anyone they talk to personally. <sup><sup>few months ago came across some twitter accounts talking about using "liebe/r" that way</sup></sup>

*I* used and received the term "liebste Marie" also while speaking to a friend to "simulate" puppy dog eyes to ask for a favour - and these puppy dog eyes where obviously meant ironically.